# How can I get C++ to 'tally up' the results and produce a plan?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm doing an exercise where I have to write a program that will suggest a subscription plan based on the users answers to a series of yes-or-no questions.

The exercise is based on this chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2fL0.jpg

Here's my code so you can see what I've done so far...

```
// Firstly, Welcome the client!
cout << " Welcome to the Wordpress subsciption sugesstion Tool!" << endl;
cout << " In order to find the right plan for you, we'll need to ask you a series of questions!" << endl;
cout << " Answer the following questions using 'y' or 'n' keys when prompted." << endl;

// secondly, Present the series of questions and prompt the user for input.
cout << 1.) Would you like to utilize free themes? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(answer = 'y')
{
    freeTheme = true;
}
else
{
    freeTheme = false;
}
cout << "\t\n 2.) Would you like to customize your themes? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(answer = 'y')
{
    customDesign = true;
}
else
{
    customDesign = false;
}
    
cout << "\t\n 3.) Will you be needing Search Engine Optimization? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(answer = 'y')
{
    seoTools = true;
}
else
{
    seoTools = false;
}
    
cout << "\t\n 4.) Is live support important for you? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(answer = 'y')
{
    liveSupport = true;
}
else
{
    liveSupport = false;
}

cout << "\t\n 5.) How much data will you need to host? 3GB, 6GB, 13GB, or unlimited(999GB)?" << endl;
cin >> storageCapacity;

if(storageCapacity = 3)
{
    costPerMonth = 0.00;
}
else if (storageCapacity = 6)
{
    costPerMonth = 5.00;
}
else if (storageCapacity = 13)
{
    costPerMonth = 8.00;
}
else if (storageCapacity = 999)
{
    costPerMonth = 25.00;
}

cout << 6.) How many years are you interest in hosting for?" << endl;
cin >> years;
```

It may seem a bit messy but I'm wracking by brain trying to solve it. What do you think? Am I on the right track? Which statements/ operators am I missing? Should I try incorporating switch statements?

Comment: I would worry about the bugs in your code before you try and tidy it up. `if(answer == 'y')` not `if(answer = 'y')` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch statement might make the code at the end with storage capacity look nicer, as well as being easy to implement but this is a matter pf preference alone, there is little to no benefit to the program itself. Also change the if statement contents from assignment  operator (=) to comparison (==) as the comment said. To clean up your if else clutter you should use:

```
bool_name = answer == desired_input;
```

eg:

```
freeTheme = answer == 'y';
```

Otherwise you could simply ask which option from the pic they want (free, blogger..etc) and use this in a switch statement. I would do this since it means the user needs to do less input, can see all the options on one line so doesn't need to think what other future options might be and it's just easier to code.